# Radiogroup swaps position in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swap, radio-group

when i click on checkbox the radio will be visible and when i uncheck it ,it will not be visible.but when i scroll down and view again same the radiogroup will be visible if i uncheck.and it repeats when i scroll down.

```
private List<MarkAttendance_info> stList;

public MarkAttendance_Adapter(List<MarkAttendance_info> students) {
    this.stList = students;

}

// Create new views
@Override
public MarkAttendance_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                            int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.mark_attendance, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    final int pos = position;

    viewHolder.tvName.setText(stList.get(position).getStudentname());

    viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(stList.get(position).getStudentid());

    viewHolder.stupkey.setText(stList.get(position).getStudentPkey());

    viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isSelected());

    viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));

    viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            MarkAttendance_info contact = (MarkAttendance_info) cb.getTag();

            contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
            stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

            if(cb.isChecked())
            {
                viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }



            Toast.makeText(
                    v.getContext(),
                    "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                            + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.grades.setTag(stList.get(position));
    setRadio(viewHolder, stList.get(position).getCheckedId());

    viewHolder.a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stList.get(position).setCheckedId(0);
            setRadio(viewHolder, stList.get(position).getCheckedId());
        }
    });
    viewHolder.b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            stList.get(position).setCheckedId(1);
            setRadio(viewHolder, stList.get(position).getCheckedId());
        }
    });
    viewHolder.c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stList.get(position).setCheckedId(2);
            setRadio(viewHolder, stList.get(position).getCheckedId());
        }
    });
    viewHolder.d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stList.get(position).setCheckedId(3);
            setRadio(viewHolder, stList.get(position).getCheckedId());
        }
    });
    viewHolder.e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stList.get(position).setCheckedId(4);
            setRadio(viewHolder, stList.get(position).getCheckedId());
        }
    });


}
private void setRadio(final ViewHolder holder, int selection) {

    System.out.println("SELECT:" + selection);
    RadioButton b1 = holder.a;
    RadioButton b2 = holder.b;
    RadioButton b3 = holder.c;
    RadioButton b4 = holder.d;
    RadioButton b5 = holder.e;

    if (selection == 0) b1.setChecked(true);
    if (selection == 1) b2.setChecked(true);
    if (selection == 2) b3.setChecked(true);
    if (selection == 3) b4.setChecked(true);
    if (selection == 4) b5.setChecked(true);

}

// Return the size arraylist
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return stList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvEmailId;
    public TextView stupkey;

    public CheckBox chkSelected;

    public RadioGroup grades;
    public RadioButton a;
    public RadioButton b;
    public RadioButton c;
    public RadioButton d;
    public RadioButton e;


    public MarkAttendance_info singlestudent;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        tvName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_student_name);

        tvEmailId = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txt_student_id);
        stupkey =(TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.student_primkey);

        grades = (RadioGroup) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_grade);

        a =(RadioButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_A);
        b =(RadioButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_B);
        c =(RadioButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_C);
        d =(RadioButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_D);
        e =(RadioButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_E);

        chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.radioButtonPresent);

    }

}

// method to access in activity after updating selection
public List<MarkAttendance_info> getStudentLists() {
    return stList;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure all of this code is relevant to your question? Please try to reduce it to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to avoid wasting people's time reading through irrelevant lines of code. Doing so might even help you to answer your own question.

Comment: It's just because you haven't set the setVisibility in onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final int pos = position;

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(stList.get(position).getStudentname());

        viewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(stList.get(position).getStudentid());

        viewHolder.stupkey.setText(stList.get(position).getStudentPkey());

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setChecked(stList.get(position).isSelected());

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setTag(stList.get(position));

        viewHolder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                MarkAttendance_info contact = (MarkAttendance_info) cb.getTag();

                contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                stList.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());

                if(cb.isChecked())
                {
                    viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }



                Toast.makeText(
                        v.getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.grades.setTag(stList.get(position));
       if (chkSelected.isChecked()) {
            viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
//            ...
    }
```

Comment: and why the radio button value swaps its position?.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking.When a view scroll to be unvisible to you , it's destroyed. And when you scrollback,it is recreated.When you recreate it , you should set status of it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to `onBindViewHolder` :

```
if(stList.get(position).isSelected()) {
    //hide the layout you need - i.e. set the WHOLE layout View.GONE
}
```

Comment: the radiobutton values are not swapping.. only problem is radiogroup. is there anything to set for radiogroup as we do for other

Comment: set Tag to RadioGroup as well

Comment: problem is visible and invisible are swapping when i click on checkbox.. how to solve it..

Comment: i do not understand you. How can you see the invisible swapping ? Can you make a video ?

Comment: think there are 10 cells in recyclerview.. each cell has got one checkbox and 5 radiobuttons.initially checkbox will be true so all the radiobuttons will be visible.now if i uncheck a checkbox and scroll down the other cells radiobuttons will also be invisible.. u got?

Comment: yes. Why my solution is wrong? Set the whole radio-group visibility to gone within onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

just put inside your getView()
viewHolder.grades.setVisibility(cb.isChecked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

Comment: am getting the values fine here.. when i uncheck the checkbox the radiogroup will not be visible this s working.. but when i scroll down the radiogroup will not be visible for other too

Comment: radiobutton is not swapping its position.. only swap thing s radiogroup.the total group itself swap..

Comment: its not the visible problem.. the visible and invisible are swapping when i click on checkbox..

Comment: can you record it to a video ?

Comment: think there are 10 cells in recyclerview.. each cell has got one checkbox and 5 radiobuttons.initially checkbox will be true so all the radiobuttons will be visible.now if i uncheck a checkbox and scroll down the other cells radiobuttons will also be invisible.. u got?